# The condition is failing with OR but not with AND

Tags: mysql, database

Query the list of CITY names from STATION that do not end with vowels. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

The STATION table is described as follows:
Field     Type
ID        NUMBER
CITY      VARCHAR2 (21)
STATE     VARCHAR2 (2)
LAT N     NUMBER
LONG W    NUMBER

Why the condition is failing with OR condition but not With AND condition i guess both should return same output?

I tried writing these queries

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE (CITY NOT LIKE'%A' OR CITY NOT LIKE'%E' OR
                                        CITY NOT LIKE'%I' OR CITY NOT LIKE'%O' OR
                                        CITY NOT LIKE'%U');
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE (CITY NOT LIKE'%A' AND CITY NOT LIKE'%E' AND
                                        CITY NOT LIKE'%I' AND CITY NOT LIKE'%O' AND
                                        CITY NOT LIKE'%U');
```

The and condition is giving correct output.

Comment: Didn't you study Boolean algebra in school?

Comment: Boolean logic is similar to natural language logic: If CITY is not finishing by A (and same for E, I, O & U) then it shows what you are searching for but for example, if CITY = Valencia, is not matching the first condition CITY NOT LIKE '%A', as one of the conditions is not matched the full query fails for that row and any other condition in the AND will be ignored. For OR, just one clause being TRUE it will pass, so, it always will be one of the clauses that will fail.

Answer (score 0):

The `OR` operator is exactly the opposite of `AND`. The `OR` operator instructs MySQL to retrieve rows that match either condition.

Let us say your city is 'Kentucky'

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE (CITY NOT LIKE'%A' OR CITY NOT LIKE'%E' OR
                                        CITY NOT LIKE'%I' OR CITY NOT LIKE'%O' OR
                                        CITY NOT LIKE'%U');
```

Every `OR` you have is `true`.
Compared to your second one `AND`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE (CITY NOT LIKE'%A' AND CITY NOT LIKE'%E' AND
                                        CITY NOT LIKE'%I' AND CITY NOT LIKE'%O' AND
                                        CITY NOT LIKE'%U');
```

The answer to your question is removing the `NOT` in your query, because `OR` and `AND` are opposite. `OR` returns row if either is true, and `AND` returns row if `ALL` conditions are true.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE (CITY LIKE'%A' OR CITY LIKE'%E' OR
                                        CITY LIKE'%I' OR CITY LIKE'%O' OR
                                        CITY LIKE'%U');
```

Hope this helps.